# Multiple StreamListeners to same Topic with Spring Cloud Stream connected to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have Spring Boot app I am using Spring Cloud Stream connecting to Kafka. I'm trying to set up two separate stream listener methods to  same kafka topic.

```
@StreamListener("countries")
    @SendTo("aggregated-statistic")
    public KStream<?, AggregatedCountry> process(KStream<Object, Country> input) {
        return input
                .groupBy((key, value) -> value.getCountryCode())
                .aggregate(this::initialize,
                        this::aggregateAmount,
                        materializedAsPersistentStore("countries", Serdes.String(),
                                Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(),
                                        new JsonDeserializer<>(AggregatedCountry.class))))
                .toStream()
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(null, value));
    }
    @StreamListener("countries")
    @SendTo("daily-statistic")
    public KStream<?, List<DailyStatistics>> daily(KStream<Object, Country> input) {
        return input
                .groupBy((key, value) -> value.getCountryCode())
                .aggregate(this::initializeDailyStatistics,
                        this::dailyStatistics,
                        materializedAsPersistentStore("daily", Serdes.String(),
                                Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(),
                                        new JsonDeserializer<>(List.class))))
                .toStream()
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(null, value));
    }
```

But when I start Spring Boot app I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "kafka-stream-f4f8166b-cbeb-42ca-b461-2b3a23885a5d-StreamThread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer was assigned partitions [kafka-stream-daily-repartition-0] which didn't correspond to subscription request [kafka-stream-countries-repartition, countries]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.handleAssignmentMismatch(ConsumerCoordinator.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:353)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:963)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:863)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:819)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:788)
```

I guess I need separate application id for each StreamListener methods but how can I configure it in application.yml file if I am listening to the same topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide two separate input bindings (and both of those can point to the same topic). You cannot use the same binding name on multiple `StreamListener`s. You can then set `application.id` for multiple `StreamListener` based processors on the input bindings. For e.g.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.countries1.consumer.applicationId
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.countries2.consumer.applicationId
```

See [this section](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_application_id) from the ref docs.

Comment: Thanks for such quick response. Your solution worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading "countries" topic twice, would be better if you read once from "countries", and send data to "daily-statistic" and "aggregated-statistic".

Reading twice is not the same thing as concurrent processing. If you want concurrency configure this parameter:

```
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    bindings:
      countries:
        destination: countries-topic
        consumer.concurrency: 6
```

And you can use a topology like:

```
@StreamListener("countries")
@SendTo({"daily-statistic", "aggregated-statistic"})
```